# Removing singleton instances from Delphi project

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, mvp

I am trying to make my first project that can be unit tested. And it is amazing how I have to rewire my brain of some vicious coding styles.

This article got me the attention that [Singletons are pathological liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

I am not trying to be radical on that, but I am used to an artifact that I am not sure how can i get rid of it

example:

```
initialization
  ModelFactory.RegisterFactoryMethod('standard.contasmovimento',
    function(AParam: Variant) : TModel
    begin
      result := TModelContasMovimento.Create(AParam);
    end);

end.
```

ModelFactory is a singleton, defined on its unit and part of the uses clause of this unit.

In my MVP structure I define each of the Models, Views and Presenters in its own unit (1 class 1 unit). All these units are available to be used, according the needs of each project. So, I use it like a parts catalog, according the project I add the units to the project and it gets automatically registered and ready to be used from the factories.

To solve the singleton problem i was thinking in move them to a framework class, so I could create the object at one point and then could use dependency injection to pass the framework object. All the factories and other environment stuff are sit there:

```
TMyFramework = class
  FModelFactory: IModelFactory;
  FViewFactory: IViewFactory;
  FPresenterFactory: IPresenterFactory;

  property ModeFactory: IModelFactory read FModelFactory;
  ...
```

My ideia is remove the singletons in a way that I can mock them in a test unit. With singletons in place I cant remove them easily for testing.

But that will make me loose the automatic initialization of each unit, an I rely on that to add the units. I don't want to manually create a list of available classes.

Is there a way to solve this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unit testing to get off the ground without a complete rewrite of all the singletons you have, I have found that just adding the ability to `Free` and re-`Create` the singletons is usually more than enough to get you started.

Assuming the singletons are instantiated in an initialization section (Ban those. They are the bane of any unit test. Go for separate registration and initialization units.), you can simply add two procedures to the interface section. Put them between conditional defines if you don't want other units in your normal project to use them:

```
{$IFDEF DUNIT}
procedure InstantiateMySingleton;
procedure FreeMySingleton;
{$ENDIF}
```

Move the code that you now have in your initialization and finalization sections to the implementation of these procedures and just call them from the initialization and finalization.

```
procedure InstantiateMySingleton;
begin
   // ...
end;

procedure FreeMySingleton;
begin
   // ...
end;

initialization
  InstantiateMySingleton;
finalization
  FreeMySingleton;
```

With this done you can start to use the InstantiateMySingleton and FreeMySingleton in your unit tests' setup and teardown methods.

All you have then left to do is to make sure that creating and destroying the singleton doesn't leak memory and is something that can actually be repeated with the same functional results every single time. One thing I have found that helps in ensuring this is to use the GUI runner and run the whole test suite twice (without exiting the GUI of course!). If there are tests that succeed on the first run and fail on the second run, you have problems in the initialization or finalization of your singleton.

Comment: And I already was wondering if and when someone will come up with the "ifdefs for testing" solution.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I don't like them either and usually avoid them like the plague. That said, when you need to get started making a "legacy" (rotten word) application testable, they can be invaluable. And bear in mind that in this case the IFDEF's are in the interface section and only serve to make stem prolific use of the procedures in the actual application. They are superfluous otherwise. And they would in fact have to go as soon as you start moving your initialization and finalization code to separate registration and initialization units.

Comment: Yes, making something testable *before* refactoring is important otherwise you cannot make sure your code works after you did the big refactoring. But you know once something works it often stays :)

Comment: @MarjanVenema I have accepted your answer because you come with a possible solution. I dont like ifdefs either, but the idea of free and recreate lead me to create a singleton that implements internally a strategy pattern that let me change its behavior for testing or production, keeping the "fixed" part minimal, since I "cannot" mock it easily (or at least beautifully)

Comment: @StefanGlienke: yes, that's why I tend to create backlog issues nowadays to address them. I know they are likely to get pushed back, but at least there is a reminder and if you have a product owner that cares about speed of delivery remaining high in the long haul, they will get executed.

Answer (score 4):

It depends if you need the instance in another class or the factory to instantiate the class at a later point. In the first case you can simply pass the constructed instance as dependency. In the other case you pass the factory. In both cases you are using dependency injection instead of looking it up in some other unit ("Don't look for things but ask for things").

Of course this requires some wire up code for the dependency ("poor man's DI") or the use of a DI container.

Dependency injection really is the only way to make things testable in a clean way because you just simply pass mocks to the SUT.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the way to solve it in the long run. Though I wouldn't ask for anything either (can lead to the much vilified service locator pattern) but I guess you mean the same as what I like to call "expect to be handed what you need, when you need it" :) Which means it can be handed to you in any non-constructor method signature as well. Constructor is just a "nice" way not to have to add arguments to all methods, while adding arguments to every method is a good way to remain stateless. Trade offs, trade offs, trade offs.

Comment: The sentence is taken from Miskos presentations and others also use it. "Ask for things" in this context means require what you need in the ctor or your methods. "Looking for things" means calling methods on collaborators to get what you should have asked for in the first place (often while violating the LoD). The service locator falls into the "looking for things" category. Also the decision if to add to the ctor or as parameter of your methods is about the lifetime and the scope. If you call the methods with the same thing over and over you most likely should have passed it to the ctor.

Comment: Yeah I know that's how "they" talk about it. It's just one of my petpeeves that "asking for what you need" doesn't automatically soekk "constructor" when heard/taken out of context. So I like to make it more explicit is all. With regard to your last sentence: not necessarily. Could be the same type, but not the same instance...

Comment: With "same thing" I meant exactly the same thing, i.e. same instance ;)

Comment: Well, that clears it up then :) Yes in that case I would go for the constructor as well, though I like to limit a class's member fields as much as possible. When you are in high performance multi-threaded code I'll take other disadvantages over having to reason about state. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, Misco is making the case about (not) using Singletons in other objects. It's a bit of a stretch but one could view a delphi unit as an object so the question is what to do to remove the Singleton dependency in the unit.

The easiest solution, and one I have been using for some time is to **move all initialization code** for a give project into one *(or several)* units who's only purpose is to do the initialization for your application.

As for your testcases, you are now free to ommit that unit and initialize *(mock)* to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

If I look enough I am sure I can find an article describing each and every design pattern either as an anti-pattern or the devil incarnate. For example, here is article that describes the Service Locator pattern as an anti-pattern:

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/

I have seen comments describing factory patterns as anti-patterns.

I have often used singletons in factories in the past and I have no problem testing the adapters/plugins/etc that I "load" with these factories in unit tests. Typically the code in singletons is simple and not something that I would test in itself. The code is tested enough just through normal use. All of the Dependency Injection libraries that I have seen include a singleton for their global container.

Where possible I like to configure my adapters in XML. The system itself is then completely modular and easy to test.

I am not saying that dependency injection is bad. Far from it. I like it. If you are building a system from scratch I would certainly advocate it as a good framework to design around and Spring4D is a good implementation. I am putting forward a different view point. I think that rewriting your system to try and take advantage of a newer or different technology should be your last port of call. It reminds me of the Joel Spolsky article about the Netscape rewrite of Navigator (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).

Comment: Dependency Injection itself has nothing to do with a singleton. I don't know where you get that from. Also the service locator is a special incarnation of a global state and involves the "spooky action at a distance" which is poison to any testability because the API lies to you and tells you nothing about what it really needs. If you find something like that easy to unit test you are blunt, no offense.

Comment: @StefanGlienke All of the dependency injection libraries that I have seen use a Singleton in some form internally. The pattern itself is not "bad". It all depends on how it is used. I was just using the service locator as an example to show searching for anti-patterns will produce links on almost all patterns.

Comment: I cannot speak for other libraries since I don't know technical details. In Spring4D you have a singleton instance of the container (that you can access using the `GlobalContainer` inline function) but you can also create your `TContainer` instance yourself and use that. In theory you can even have multiple containers in one application and connect then with each other (by writing your own container extensions as that is not supported ootb). The singleton leads to bad code as you can access it from places that are not supposed to access it.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I would say it slightly differently. The singleton can lead to bad code. That is not necessarily the case. In any system where you want to "ask for things" you need to have a place that is common between the where it is registered and where it can be requested. That is by definition a singleton.  Ultimately it comes down to how you use it. Something like DI vs a Singleton Factory is, in a way, protecting the developer from themselves.

Comment: You are confusing the Singleton pattern where one instance is forced on you without possibility to be changed (as described by the GoF) and classes that only have one instance in an application to work. The difference is that in the 2nd case you still can mock this and pass a fake thing while you can not with a global state that is forced by the design. I suggest watching Misko Heverys clean code talk on that subject to understand that.

Comment: @StefanGlienke I will take a look at his talk this evening.